# Create a method from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

So I have a string `"getNumber"`:

I would like to use this string as a method for an object: `myObj.getNumber()`

Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as:

```
myObj['getNumber']();
```

Answer (score 1):

There two ways to access value from js object .. one is dot notation `.` and other is square bracket notation `[]`, which allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables.

```
var key = 'getNumber';
myObj[key]();
```

More information on [Mozilla, working with object guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).